# Concurrency violation:- the UpdateCommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records

Tags: c#, dataset, dataadapter

We are using windows formms. In the form we have gridview in which we perform insert a new row and update existing row together. And for the process below is the code,

```
OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(sql, conn);
OracleCommandBuilder oraCmdBuilder = new  OracleCommandBuilder(adapter);
OracleDataAdapter adap = new OracleDataAdapter();
adap.SelectCommand = new OracleCommand(sql, conn);

adap.InsertCommand = oraCmdBuilder.GetInsertCommand();
adap.InsertCommand.Connection = conn;
adap.UpdateCommand = oraCmdBuilder.GetUpdateCommand();
adap.UpdateCommand.Connection = conn;
adap.DeleteCommand = oraCmdBuilder.GetDeleteCommand();
adap.DeleteCommand.Connection = conn;
adap.UpdateBatchSize = 100;

int i = adap.Update(deltaTable);
```

Where `InsertCommand` works fine and throws exception in `adap.Update(deltaTable);` as below,

> Concurrency violation: the UpdateCommand affected 0 of the expected 1
>   records. we tried to add acceptchanges before update method, but that
>   change was affecting delete . The row was not deleting.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Comment: Have you noticed [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3388100/concurrency-violation-the-updatecommand-affected-0-of-the-expected-1-records) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9521355/concurrency-violation-the-updatecommand-affected-0-of-the-expected-1-records-v) before posting this as new question?

Comment: Or this http://stackoverflow.com/a/32558609/2946329

Comment: Adding ConflictOption.OverwriteChanges repeats the save or any action multiple times by itself.

Comment: @user703526 can you pl provide the example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced with this problem and below reasons

1) In your `update` query you have controlled data with original data before updating. To solve remove this conditions from query. If you remove condition then it turns to `last modified win`. The conditions have `@original` prefix. Query like

```
WHERE CustomerID = @Original_CustomerID OR @Original_CustomerID IS NULL AND  customer ID IS NULL
```

2) Before `Update` in your code anywhere you have `Row.AcceptChanges()`